# Password system. How do I allow 3 incorrect guesses while allowing the program to continue if the guess is correct

Tags: python, loops, passwords

The program needs to allow the user 3 incorrect attempts to write the password. However if they get the password attempt right, I want the program to print 'nice'.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
def main():

    n = 2

    for i in range(0, 3, 1):

        attempt = input('Enter password: ')


        if attempt != 'password':
            print('Incorrect. ' + str(n) + ' attempts left')

        n = int(n) - 1

        else:
            print('nice')
```

Comment: The word you're looking for is `break`.

Answer (score 1):

```
max_retries = 3
for i in range(max_retries):
    passwd = input('\nEnter password: ')
    if passwd == 'password':
        print('\nnice')
        break
    print('Incorrect.  %d attempts left' % (max_retries-i-1))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
n = 2
for i in range(0, 3, 1):
    attempt = raw_input('Enter password: ')
    if attempt != 'password':
        print('Incorrect. ' + str(n) + ' attempts left')
        n = int(n) - 1
    elif n > 0:
        print('nice')
    else:
        print('no attempts left')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Dude, in my opinion this answer doesn't need to explain. But anyway feel free to downvote me :D

Comment: *Dude* it wasn't me who downvoted, and I was just trying to help you, you know, avoid that downvote.

Answer (score -1):

```
for x in range(3):
pass_correct=False
password = "password"
attempt=raw_input("Enter password: ")
if attempt == password:
     pass_correct=True
     break
else:
    print "incorrect, " + str(2-x) + " attempts left"
if pass_correct:
    print "nice"
else:
    print "no attempts left"
```

succinct